# react native project creating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

Error occurred while trying to create project directory.

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'App1'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1396:3)
    at setProjectDirectory (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js:62:24)
    at createFromTemplate (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js:89:34)
    at createProject (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js:166:10)
    at Object.initialize [as func] (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js:184:9)
    at Command.handleAction (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:106:23)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:482:17)
    at C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1283:65
    at Command._chainOrCall (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1177:12)
    at Command._parseCommand (C:\Users\wupu0\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\7930a8670f922cdb\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:1283:27)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

these are the errors

Answer (score 0):

windows is not giving permission to the user to create a folder inside system drive. To solve this:

Right Click

The Folder > Properties > Security Tab

Click on Edit to change Permissions > Select the user and give Full